# Dynamically adding views causes problems with styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I created two projects from scratch which are supposed to produce the same result: a few buttons with special style.
**First project:**
activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttons_panel_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // default menu part
}
```

**Second project:**
activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttons_panel_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

buttons_panel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LinearLayout buttonsPanelContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_panel_container);

        View buttonPanelView = null;

        buttonPanelView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons_panel, null);

        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) buttonsPanelContainer;
        insertPoint.addView(buttonPanelView, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    // default menu part
}
```

---

The first project works as it should => all buttons are visible, properly styled and clickable.
Buttons in the second project are **invisible**, although clickable.
Could please someone tell me why creating layout dynamically causes problems with the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get LayoutInflater using application context use activity context instead (application context is not themed). In your case it will be just `LayoutInflater.from(this)`